# Pagination System Bug

Tags: bug, new-nav, filtering, pagination

#### Current behaviour

If you select a **page** which won't appear if you **select to display more entries in one page**, this happens:

[image: That's a miss]

#### Exact steps to reproduce

1. Open any tab, for example [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/bounties/size).
2. Make sure you've chosen `15` or `30` items per page:
   [image: Per Page]
3. Open the last page.
4. Set the *per page* amount to one bigger than set currently.
5. That's a miss!

#### Expected behaviour

I think it should get you to the **last possible page**, or to the **first one** instead of showing a miss.